# Uncaught Error: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, indexof, typeerror

I have an array and I'm trying to keep in an array the matched element like:

```js
myarr = ["80299", "82000", "812323", "852258"];
var res = myarr.filter(x => x.indexOf("02") !== -1)
alert(res);
```

But it gives an error "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined" How can i fix it?

Comment: The code you provided does not error. You'll need to give a more precise example of the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/5pyw1exe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
 myarr.filter(function(el, index, arr){return (el.indexOf('02') > -1)})
```